# GurobiPy Tutorials and hands on from beginner to advanced

Tags: optimization, python, gurobi, gurobipy

What is the best way to start modelling with `GurobiPy`, in order to utilize it, for research purpose (**i.e.** more complicated problems)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Useful links:
[Intro](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/quickstart_mac/cs_python.html)
[Python API](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/py_python_api_overview.html)- queries, attributes etc.
Some [basic examples](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/10.0/examples/python_examples.html) in Python demonstrating how to use callback, lazy constraints (delayed row generation) etc.
[Python API Examples](https://www.gurobi.com/jupyter_models/)-Beginner to Advanced
Also check the [Gurobi-ML](https://gurobi-machinelearning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/firststeps-introduction.html) integration